# Extracting and reading large, encoded files from within a JSON stream

Tags: java, json

We have some rather large, base64-encoded files within simple JSON:

```
{
"name": "ox",
"file": "blah base64 very long file blahblah",
"file2"    :    "yet another blah base64 very long file blahblah"}
...
}
```

Due to the size of these embedded, encoded files, I need to stream the data and so I'm using JsonParser.

However, JsonParser does not seem to have a way to "look" at where the stream is at close enough. It does have a `getString()`, but that would pull the large, embedded file (~1GB) into memory.

I tried `JsonParser.getLocation().getStreamOffset()`, but the starting position is just after the name, and the variation in whitespace makes it difficult to accurately predict the location of the object in the stream.

So here's what I have:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/jsonParseEmbeddedFile/src/main/resources/json01.json"));
    JsonParser jp = Json.createParser(is);
    while (jp.hasNext()) {
        Event e = jp.next();
        if(e == Event.KEY_NAME) {
            switch(jp.getString()) {
            case "name":
                System.out.print(jp.getString() + ": ");
                jp.next();
                System.out.println(jp.getString());
                break;
            case "file":
                System.out.print(jp.getString()+": ");
                jp.next();
                System.out.println(jp.getString());
            }
        }
    }
    is.close();
    jp.close();
    t1();
}

private static void t1() throws Exception {
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/jsonParseEmbeddedFile/src/main/resources/json01.json"));
    JsonParser jp = Json.createParser(is);
    long start = 0L;
    long end = 0L;
    long start2 = 0L;
    long end2 = 0L;
    while (jp.hasNext()) {
        Event e = jp.next();
        if(e == Event.KEY_NAME) {
            switch(jp.getString()) {
            case "name":
                System.out.print(jp.getString() + ": ");
                jp.next();
                System.out.println(jp.getString());
                break;
            case "file":
                start=jp.getLocation().getStreamOffset();
                jp.next();
                end=jp.getLocation().getStreamOffset();
                break;
            case "file2":
                start2=jp.getLocation().getStreamOffset();
                jp.next();
                end2=jp.getLocation().getStreamOffset();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    is.close();
    jp.close();
    System.out.println((char) 10 + "file results:");
    InputStream is2 = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/jsonParseEmbeddedFile/src/main/resources/json01.json"));
    is2.skip(start);
    for(int i = 0; i < (end - start);i++) {
        System.out.print((char) is2.read());
    }
    is2.close();
    System.out.println((char) 10 + "file2 results:");
    InputStream is3 = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/jsonParseEmbeddedFile/src/main/resources/json01.json"));
    is3.skip(start2);
    for(int i = 0; i < (end2 - start2);i++) {
        System.out.print((char) is3.read());
    }
    is3.close();
}
```

Here are the results:

```
name: ox
file: blah base64 very long file blahblah
name: ox
file results:
: "blah base64 very long file blahblah"
file2 results:
:    "yet another blah base64 very long file blahblah"
```

How can I find the beginning of the embedded object reliably?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: 2 question: 1 is there a way to read the embedded file in a stream instead of what the example does (getString()). 2 if not how to determine the start of the embedded file without character comparing to figure out the start?

Comment: I personally use Google's GSON library to parse a stream of JSON data.